# Why Typescript ternary operator doesn't narrow falsy value as well as conditional short-circuit

Tags: typescript

While trying to refine the TS types `emotion-js` (cf. https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/pull/2297#discussion_r596749648) we found an unexpected behaviour.

```
type Falsy = false | "" | 0 | null | undefined

declare const foo: string;

const res1: (Falsy | { test: true }) = foo && { test: true };

// why infered type is not the same as for the above?
const res2: (Falsy | { test: true }) = foo ? { test: true } : foo;
```

(see [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgGwM4igXigM0U6AfKAIkKgIAZSoA7AVwQUpqoBMJMBLKiZgKB9YDGCOACdoAgPZUkwLBIkAuKDJGcA5gG4%20k6bLFIAjEoAU8ZKgIBvKMAgylwETWgBfAJTo5EqADIfUa1t7GydXLR4AegioAHcAC1ROTAgxZhtwaHYkaglZYDjoJDgAW2g4bMwJERsCqDgAIwkANwgAfh4dGSh9ACYTMxRKQLtgB1Cod09K71aAmxGx5wmoJWmNIA))

Why is TS not able to narrow the second type to `"" | { test: true }`

Comment: I believe this is design limitation. Consider next example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABBA9gOwM4BdEDMUoBci2cAlmgOYDcwwZuAFAIT4oCUA3sIr8utkQAPRAF48BWgF9gQA
Ts is unable to figure out that `foo` might be empty string, it is still just a string. Same with `number`

Comment: This is undoubtedly a design limitation in TypeScript but I haven't found an existing issue in GitHub that's obviously related.

Comment: Eh, I think [microsoft/TypeScript#33618](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33618) is as close as I'm going to find: "Narrowing patterns need to be identified syntactically, so we have to 'pay for' all of them".